# data not storing in rasa

Tags: tensorflow, text, rasa

I need help. i am new to data science and recently i've started to learn about rasa. after writing all the intents and entities in nlu.md and stories in stories.md, i saved the files and trained to train my assistant by rasa train nlu command.

Data in the files are not getting saved. when i close the file and reopens it, only the default intents are show and not the intents that i had written.

the error msg in my anaconda prompt is:

****Exception: Not all required importable packages are installed. To use this pipeline, you need to install the missing dependencies. Please install the package(s) that contain the module(s): tensorflow_text****

this is the error i got. i have already installed tensorflow. and i am using windows 10. someplease reply help

Answer (score 1):

`tensorflow_text` is not yet available for windows. However, this will only matter if you are using `convert` components in your pipeline. You can use any other components and to circumvent this problem. As to your problem of the intents not getting saved - unless you're working in Rasa X, that sounds like a problem with your code editor; check if you can edit and save the files to the location you're using in general.

Comment: thankyou for your help. i have tried in ubuntu. but my issue has not yet resolved. i was getting a new error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use ConveRT featurizer that requires tensorflow-text. To keep the requirements lean, tensorflow-text is an optional dependency, therefore you have to install it separately within the environment that you installed Rasa. Another solution would be to use another featurizer (maybe spacy's featurizer). Also, do train by typing `rasa train` rather than `rasa train nlu` since it will only train your nlu model (that classifies entities and intents) but will not train the dialogue management part.